# How can i build /hardware/libhardware/tests/nusensor?

Tags: android, build, sensors, android.mk

I'm just beginner of Android and i'm using kitkat(4.4.4) source.

When i try to bulid android (not kernel), always don't build

```
 /hardware/libhardware/tests/nusensor.
```

That's why i can't find its result excutable file named test-nusensor though i need it.

How can I build that file in that directory? and How can I execute result of build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have already built the entire android source you can build the nusensor-test module seperately. Follow these steps to build that module alone -

- Run `source build/envsetup.sh` from the android root folder
- Run `lunch` and select the correct device you want to build for.
- Go to `/hardware/libhardware/tests/nusensor` folder and run `mm`
- The executable should get generated and it will be present in `out/target/product/msm8974/system/bin/` with the name `test-nusensors`
- Push the executable to the device - `adb push out/target/product/msm8974/system/bin/test-nusensors /system/bin`
- To run it use the command `adb shell /system/bin/test-nusensors`